# How is user_engagement event generated in firebase analytics?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I have seen a param named `firebase_screen_class` (along with `engagement_time_msec`, `firebase_event_origin` and `firebase_screen_id`) in the `user_engagement` event in bigQuery, it contains the name of activity classes in my app. Please, can you explain these params and how is the `user_engagement` event generated?

I also wonder whether this can be useful to get the quantity of impressions or screen views of the activities in my app.

Answer (score 12):

The user_engagement event is triggered when a user interacts with the app for a minimum duration.

This can be controlled using the [setMinimumSessionDuration()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.html#setMinimumSessionDuration(long)) method call, also the timeout for a session can be controlled using the [setSessionTimeoutDuration()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.html#setSessionTimeoutDuration(long)) call.

For tracking screen view it is recommended to integrate [Firebase with GTM](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v5/). Take a look at this [tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20161231051647/http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2016/10/18/firebase-analytics-for-apps/) for implementation details.

Comment: So there has to be a interaction of at least 10 seconds (default) for the user_engagement event to be triggered?

Comment: Yes, although that 10 seconds can be broken up over multiple intervals within the session timeout period.  More details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40999239/how-exactly-do-firebase-analytics-handle-session-duration-timeouts/41192499#41192499).

Comment: @Dan Morenus so, the user_engagement event that I saw in my exported-to-bigquery data is the one explained in the setCurrentScreen (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics#setCurrentScreen(android.app.Activity, java.lang.String, java.lang.String) ) documentation?

Comment: @josue.0 Short answer, yes.  Firebase Analytics generates engagement events automatically and includes the current screen information with them as the user navigates through your app.  [Here's a summary](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317485?hl=en) of the events that Firebase Analytics generates automatically.

Comment: You may implement custom parameters, related to your screen views, if needed. This is described in the “Log events” document, [1] under the “Log events” subtitle. [1] https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/ios/events

Comment: these action are related to session_start event and not for user_engagement  event
see [Doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.html#parameters_4)

Comment: "user_engagement - when the app is in the foreground or webpage is in focus for at least one second." [ GA4 Automatically collected events](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9234069)