# What is the periodicity behind user_engagement events?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-bigquery, analytics, firebase-analytics

Basically, im trying to make sense out of user_engagement events, i've read that they are triggered once the user is with the app on first plane for at least 10 seconds, but once they are with the app open and triggered the first user_engagement event, when is the next one gonna be triggered? After 10 minutes of use? after another 10 seconds? I couldnt find that number.

Comment: According to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43054696/how-is-user-engagement-event-generated-in-firebase-analytics, you can control the session duration by calling ` setMinimumSessionDuration()`. This also means you shouldn't assume it's a fixed value, and instead use its `engagement_time_msec` parameter to determine the engagement duration.

Comment: Hmmm, i see!! Thanks Frank!